# How to create custom JUnit5 Extensions

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, junit5-extension-model

**Is it possible to create a custom extension like I could've created a `@Rule` in JUnit4?**

```
public class MockMetadataServiceRule extends ExternalResource {   
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        //some setup
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
       // some teardown
    }
}
```

Then, I can do this with inside the test class with **JUnit5**

```
@BeforeAll
public static void init() {
    MetadataServiceFactory.setService(MockitoMockMetadataService.getMock());
}

@AfterAll
public static void teardown() {
    MetadataServiceFactory.setService(null);
}
```

but I presume you can `@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)` now?

**EDIT**:
The example of my extension in case @nullpointer link disappeared. Thanks.

```
public class MockMetadataServiceExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        MetadataServiceFactory.setService(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        MetadataServiceFactory.setService(MockitoMockMetadataService.getMock());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**. It's possible to create [custom extensions](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) in Junit5. In fact that is what **[`@ExtendWith`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/)** is intended for :

> To register a custom `YourExtension` for all tests in a particular
>   class and its subclasses, you would annotate the test class as
>   follows.

```
@ExtendWith(YourExtension.class)
class YourTests {
    // ...
}
```

---

An example fo the `BeforeAllCallback`, `AfterAllCallback` could be found at [spring-framework.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.java)

---

> Multiple extensions can be registered together like this:

```
@ExtendWith({ YourExtension1.class, YourExtension2.class })
class YourTests {
```

Comment: @LazerBanana Linked the example in the answer.

Comment: can i have multiple extensions on the class ?

Comment: @LazerBanana yes you can, just specify them comma separated in the form of a list.